# Php form validate and post are working but not together?

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

In order to work properly my form needs to be set up to first check the validation and then post the data if the validation passes. This is fine but I am not sure how to combine the validation code with the post code in the form action. Example if the action is: `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">` the form validates correctly but does not send anywhere! If I change the form action to `action="contact-engine.php">` then the form is posted but without validation! With this in mind I need to combine into the action both the validation and then (once passed validation) the contact-engine.php problem is I simply do not know how to do this? I really am a learner in php and this is complicated for me! Any help is really appreciated I have been working on this from now for a few days! (N.B. both pages are .php) Full code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Help!</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = "";
    $name = $email = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

//Name
    if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
    else
    {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
    {
    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }}

//Email
   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
   {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
   else
   {
   $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
   {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
   }}
}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>

<form method="post" id="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p><br />

    <div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
        <span class="asterix">* </span>Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="name" class="border" size="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) {echo $_POST['name']; } ?>">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-font" style=" margin-top: 20px;">
        <span class="asterix">* </span>Email: (please double check enty)<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" class="border" size="25" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) {echo $_POST['email']; } ?>"><span class="error">
        <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>


And below is the contact-engine code:
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Engine</title>
</head>

<body>

    <br />Name:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?><br />
    <br />Email:<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not need to put the `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">` This will submit the form to same page. 

The way it is done is by sending the form data to your `contact-engine.php` file and perform validation there.

Comment: Hello Butterfruit, but if the validation is done on the contact-engine.php page if there are errors how are they displayed on the initial page? Is there no way to edit the action perhaps by adding an if statement saying if the validation is good then send the form to contact-engine.php? Thank you for your help : )

Comment: you have to use javascript to make a validation before sending the form

Comment: Hello Andrei, I guess that would be ok because there is not data base connection here so a javascript validation would be fine and quicker as it would not have to go to a server. I will take a look at this way and hopefully find it easier. I got a lot of the code above from w3schools and they take me up to validation only! Great I now have a form I cannot do anything with! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. This is a simple code below through which you can achieve this:

```
//sample index.php file
<?php
  include 'submitted.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="foo" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I am submitting the form to the same page using post method. But, I have included another file which is `include 'submitted.php'`.

Here is the test script inside the `submitted.php`

```
//sample submitted.php
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['foo']))
 {
    if(strlen($_POST['foo']) < 5){
  echo "String length too small";
  }
  else
  {
   echo $_POST['foo'];
  }
 }
?>
```

For test, it simply checks if the length is more than five or not. If it is not, the error message is displayed on the same page where your page is present.

Test it yourself too.

Comment: Ok, I have changed foo to my email address and it sent it to me : ) I am sure I am now on the right track to being able to fix my problem. I will use your code here and add it into my form. I was about to just give up after 3 days of trying and try doing it with jQuery. I am sure I can work this out now because of your help : ) Thank you so much, for your time and help. When I am good at php I will help others.

Comment: Yup, you can always make it better and better. All the best :)