# Form Validation not working in php mysql page moved on form data handling php file without form validation?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I made a form in php and I want to insert form entry in database. My form have some validation rules, When I fill the form even wrong entries and hit submit button it moved on next form data handling php file but not validate the entries here is my code.

```
<pre>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$regErr = $nameErr = $misErr = $vbErr = $statErr = $tmErr = "";
$reg = $name = $mis = $vb = $stat = $tm = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if (empty($_POST["Reg"]))
     {$regErr = "Reg ID is required";}
     else
     {
     $reg = $_POST["Reg"];
}
   if (empty($_POST["Name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
     else
     {
     $name = $_POST["Name"];

          // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
     {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["Mis"]))
     {$misErr = "Please Enter Marks";}
   else
     {
     $mis = $_POST["Mis"];
     // check if value entered is Numeric
     if(!is_numeric($mis)) {
    $misErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
     }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["Vb"]))
     {$vbErr = "Please Enter Marks";}
   else
     {
     $vb = $_POST["Vb"];
     // check if value entered is Numeric
     if(!is_numeric($vb)) {
    $vbErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
     }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["Stat"]))
     {$statErr = "Please Enter Marks";}
   else
     {
     $stat = $_POST["Stat"];
     // check if value entered is Numeric
     if(!is_numeric($stat)) {
    $statErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
     }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["Tmarks"]))
     {$tmErr = "Please Enter Marks";}
   else
     {
     $tm = $_POST["Tmarks"];
     // check if value entered is Numeric
     if(!is_numeric($tm)) {
    $tmErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
     }
     }     
}
?>


Here is my Form Code..


<form method="post" action="insert.php"> 
<table width=600 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2 style='color:white;'>
<tr>
<td>Registration#:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Reg"><span class="error">* <?php echo $regErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Student Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Name"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>MIS Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Mis"><span class="error">*<?php echo $misErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>VB.NET Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Vb"><span class="error">*<?php echo $vbErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stat Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Stat"><span class="error">*<?php echo $statErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject Total Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Tmarks"><span class="error">*<?php echo $tmErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<p style='margin-left:300px;'><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>

</pre>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: start using brute force method. echo out the data values at different points and see if validation and everything is working smoothly or not. ALSO...is `insert.php` is the name of above file or some different file?

Comment: Insert.php another file where I coded database connection and inserting functionality.

Comment: I am beginner and not know the brute force method. :(

Comment: Brute force method is nothing but putting echo at different points to test where code is stucking.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are submitting the data to another file that is `insert.php`. It is not going through the validation in your code. You have to put this validation code into the `insert.php` file.

For example you have a file which has form like this:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now this form will be submitted to `insert.php` where you will apply the validation.
Something like this:

```
//insert.php
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  //validate name here
  //then insert into database..

?>
```

If you want to show the validation in same page in which your form is present then refer to the [answer of THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497949/php-form-validate-and-post-are-working-but-not-together/21498270#21498270).

Comment: Sorry by following your above method now new error occurred and that is on php script file like insert.php there is variable defined for error and now in another form file that variables used with form field in span tag, and I got error on form file that there is no error variable found.. :(

Comment: I delete these two lines from my code and put all php code in my form file. if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection))
  {  die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }     Now that error is gone, my form validation works and submission also works but not data insert into database even it found the database but not insert data in database .. I got no error or warning on screen.